Inference with LLava v1.6 Mistral model on Amazon SageMaker
I've deployed the following model llava-hf/llava-v1.6-mistral-7b-hf in Amazon SageMaker simply pasting deployment code from model card (https://huggingface.co/llava-hf/llava-v1.6-mistral-7b-hf).  Deployment seems to have gone well, and in the same notebook in Amazon SageMaker I tried to test inference by using boto3 client and invoke_endpoint function (I want to send an image and prompt asking model to describe what's in the image). The complete deployment and inference code from the Amazon SageMaker notebook looks like the following:
# DEPLOYMENT PART:

import sagemaker
import boto3
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel

try:
    role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
except ValueError:
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    role = iam.get_role(RoleName='sagemaker_execution_role')['Role']['Arn']

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'llava-hf/llava-v1.6-mistral-7b-hf',
    'HF_TASK':'image-text-to-text'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.37.0',
    pytorch_version='2.1.0',
    py_version='py310',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)

# INFERENCE PART:

import json
from PIL import Image 
import requests

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
endpoint_name = 'huggingface-pytorch-inference-2024-06-22-21-48-42-168'

url = "https://www.ikea.com/pl/pl/images/products/silvtjaern-pojemnik__1150132_pe884373_s5.jpg?f=xl"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
prompt = "[INST] <image>\nWhat is shown in this image? [/INST]"

payload = json.dumps(prompt)

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    ContentType='application/json',
    Body=payload
)

result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
print(result)

My goal is to invoke endpoint for inference using Lambda function and API GW from outside of AWS, and therefore I first tried to test inference locally from the SageMaker notebook, but after running this inference code I've got the following error in the notebook:
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 payload = json.dumps(prompt)
----> 3 response = client.invoke_endpoint(
      4     EndpointName=endpoint_name,
      5     ContentType='application/json',
      6     Body=payload
      7 )
      9 result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
     10 print(result)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:565, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    561     raise TypeError(
    562         f"{py_operation_name}() only accepts keyword arguments."
    563     )
    564 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 565 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:1021, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
   1017     error_code = error_info.get("QueryErrorCode") or error_info.get(
   1018         "Code"
   1019     )
   1020     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
-> 1021     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
   1022 else:
   1023     return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "The checkpoint you are trying to load has model type `llava_next` but Transformers does not recognize this architecture. This could be because of an issue with the checkpoint, or because your version of Transformers is out of date."

Can someone help me understand what's wrong here and how to actually invoke this model using Lambda and Python boto3 client?
I checked the following docs
https://huggingface.co/llava-hf/llava-v1.6-mistral-7b-hf
https://medium.com/@liltom.eth/deploy-llava-1-5-on-amazon-sagemaker-168b2efd2489
https://medium.com/@vishaaly/how-to-deploy-llava-models-to-sagemaker-endpoints-25a94a58f98c
How to perform inference with a Llava Llama model deployed to SageMaker from Huggingface?
but no similar issue found.

Just to add that I've tried to install transformers from the repo with pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git  and then repeat the deplyment and inference process but I got the same error.

Did you follow the process in the medium blog to include the inference.py?

Hi Marc, I haven’t add inference file. I also try to invoke predict method on predictor object, as it should work out od the box inside HF DLC (am I right?) but I’ve got the same error.
